# Stop function automatically at specific time

Tags: php, yii

I want to write a php function in Yii, which starts something (race between colleagues). If nobody hits the end button before 12 am, it has to stop automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Right now, it inserts a row with startDate, but I'm not sure, how can I check until the specified time, if the end button was pressed or not.

Comment: You should add more details to your question before you start getting downvoted.

Comment: It's the full task, so i can't add more details. But thanks.

Comment: How about a cron job

Comment: yes a cron job can do that job. There are some extensions provided and here is one:https://github.com/fedemotta/yii2-cronjob